# Short story with a vampire who is befriended by robots

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to recover a vampire related post-apocalyptic short story.

A lone vampire is facing a world with no more humans to feed on. He cannot die, but is so weak that he can barely get out of his coffin. The only "people" remaining are robots, one of whom befriends him.

Comment: One question per post please. The reason is that, for example, I can answer the 2nd but not the 1st.

Comment: I can't seem to get enough of these kind of stories -- I am intrigued by the brief description of the vampire helping the human girl.

Comment: The second question: I think the robot becomes a sort of vampire, feeding on other robots' electric power. It is perhaps called The Stainless Steel Leech and was written probably 50 or more years ago.

Comment: Are these from the same collection of stories? (It's acceptable to ask about multiple stories only if they're in the same anthology.)

Comment: Also, please specify what type of stories: are they comics, movies, short stories, novels, volumes of a trilogy, or what?

Comment: I've edited out the first part of the question (noting that @releseabe says they have an answer for you). You should re-ask that as a separate question...

Comment: stainless steel leech by zelazney i am now pretty sure having googled it.

Comment: @releseabe - I'm sure there was a golden age story that was similar. The last vampire buries himself for centuries and wakes to find that everyone is now descended from carrots.

Comment: @Laurel Why would them being in the same anthology make it acceptable? If their goal was to identify the anthology then it would make sense to mention as many stories as they can remember from it, but as long as the goal is to identify individual stories they need to be separate questions.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - You've hit the nail on the head. If they were in the same anthology we could identify that (and in passing mention the name of the two stories as confirmation)

Comment: Sorry... I see now that the comments discussed the story I came up with. I was researching it independently, and didn't submit initially because my internet connection was disrupted. Looking back, I see the story was brought up well before I posted.

Answer (score 11):

"The Stainless Steel Leech" by Roger Zelazny.

The narrator is a vampiric robot.

> Fritz is a vampire, which is a terrible and tragic thing. He is so undernourished
> that he can no longer move about, but he cannot die either, so he lies in his
> casket and dreams of times gone by. One day, he will ask me to carry him
> outside into the sunlight, and I will watch him shrivel and dim into peace and
> nothingness and dust. I hope he doesn't ask me soon.